# Deploying static assets to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline, assets

Heroku now recommends not to use asset_sync (which it used to in the past)

Since this is new from last week, and I've been using asset_sync successfully, what am I suppose to use now?

user assets:precompile everytime? manually upload static assets to s3? what happens in other environments?

What is the recommended flow now that asset_sync is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

While the deployment warning is new, the fact that heroku doesn't recommend to use asset sync is not new.
You can see this documentation article which details the reasons behind this choice: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/please-do-not-use-asset-sync

The recommendation is to use a CDN: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn
You can link this CDN to fetch your assets directly from your application, as they will be cached and fetched only once.

This will actually improve your performance, as S3 is not a CDN. An asset is always served from the same location. Cloudfront or Cloudflare will serve the asset from the nearest server to the person requesting the data, improving latency.

Comment: So that means I need heroku to serve static assets? Right now, using asset_sync I push the assets to s3 and then cloudfront takes the assets from there.

Comment: Yes, your app will serve the assets.